# Downloadable Documents

Tags: posts, media-library, uploads

I have Press Release Section on my page where i would like to be able to add documents pdf, ms doc's etc. 
Every time when i add new document to a post I would like download button to appear so user will be able to download that document. Could anyone point me at right direction or maybe there is a plugin existing which does that.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to insert the download into the post as @kaiser says, you can automate:

```
$download = get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=application/pdf&post_parent='.$post->ID );

if ($download) {
    foreach ( $download as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id).'" target="_blank" class="download">Download PDF</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is what I'm looking for I will try that thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

[image]

When you insert a file into a post/page/whatever, you get a `<a>`-download link.

[image]

Then you can [style this link](http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/) as you want. Just insert the styles you need into your `style.css` file.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few plugins out there but the one that stands out is [**WordPress Download Monitor**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/) which works great and has many many features, one of them is creating a download button template for easy styling as a shortcode for even easier page/post insertion.

Comment: Yeah thats a nice plugin, well designed.